# Job posted at a higher pay grade level, but I'm not being offered that grade

Tags: negotiation, job-offer, promotion

I applied and successfully interviewed for a position in a different department in my company. The job was posted on our HR site as a grade 20.  I am currently two grades below that, but have been waiting for a promised promotion to an 18 for over 6 months (job grades are even numbers).  The problem with the promotion in my current position is that my department is not doing all that well financially and senior managers above mine won't approve the extra $3k to bring my salary up to the bottom of the 18 pay scale (I can't get the 18 grade promotion without being in the 18 pay grade range).

The people in the department that I just interviewed with have given me an oral acceptance and really want me to work for them. However, the HR person hinted that there may be a problem with the grade/pay and said they are "working on it". As I expected, they demoted the position to an 18 since I currently am a 16 and they substantially lowered the starting salary from what was advertised. I told the person with whom I interviewed that I've been waiting for the promotion to 18, but I don't know how much control he has. In contrast to my current department, which has been shrinking over the years, this new group is growing and hiring four new people other than me. Now that they offered me the job at 18, how should I attempt to negotiate being hired at a 20 as the job was originally posted? I have worked for my company for eight years and, despite excellent reviews every year, have not been promoted yet from the 16 where I started and have gotten paltry 2% or less increases in salary each year. My current manager said I've been doing the job of an 18, so I don't think being offered the 20 is unreasonable, especially if that is what they would give someone coming in off the street.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [workplace.se]! The best questions here inspire answers that explain *why* or *how* as explained in our [help/on-topic]. Right now you are asking us what you should push for which isn't something we can easily provide advice on, so if you read over our [help/dont-ask] and then [edit] your question, we would love to help!

Comment: Perhaps they did make a mistake. How can they legitimately deny me the grade 20, though, if I have all of the qualifications?

Comment: "They" can do what they please so long as they break no laws. Often, budgets are what drive whether or not people get promotions. Believe it or not, there is a lot of politics that goes into departmental budgets. If you are not being treated appropriately, it may be time to take your skills elsewhere.

Answer (score 13):

Is the job offer written somehow (i.e. HR website, email, job posting site)? If so, that is the position you applied for. If you get an offer at the lower level, simply say no. I know it may be hard, but they already acknowledged you work harder then you get paid for. So why would they give you more money, if they have you for less? It doesn't sound like they're treating you too well.

If they come back and offer you the Grade 18 or 16 pay, you can also try negotiating with them. If they posted for a Grade 20, they should have the money in the budget for a Grade 20 person to come onboard, no matter where from. Do not let your company bully you around though. You'll always have your previous job at Grade 18, as long as you handle this professionally, and explain your reasons for turning it down (if that's your choice).

Best of luck!

Comment: All set. I put forth my argument and was offered the job at the grade and pay originally posted!  Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Remember to Mark as a answer